# Extract row value and combinate them on another df by indicating specific row value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a data.frame made like this

```
data.frame(
  V = c(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 3.4),
  Val = c("l", "m", "s", "z"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

 #  V  Val
 # 1.1  l
 # 1.2  m
 # 2.1  s
 # 3.4  z
```

and i want to obtain the text contained on the val column, selecting the V values that i want.

For example, i choose 1.1 and 1.2

i want output like this:

```
 Val
 l m
```

How could i do?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: `df1$Val[1:2]` returns the first two values,  For specific  'Val', use `paste(df1$Val[df1$V %in% c(1.1, 1.2)], collapse=' ')`

Comment: No, I need to create a new data frame where the text is pasted and separated with a space

Comment: The comment wasn't completed! Thank u. I try immediately

Answer (score 0):

For checking multiple values in one column and get the corresponding values in another column, we can use `%in%`, then we can `paste` the values into a single string

```
newdat <- data.frame(Val= paste(df1$Val[df1$V %in% c(1.1, 1.2)], 
                    collapse=' '), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```